# How to create a form with text and file input in react and send form data to server using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to send the form data with text and file inputs. By using multer i am able to only fetch file not the text data.
Here is the form

```
import React from 'react'
const Addplayer=()=>{  
        return(
        <>
            <h1>Add player here</h1>
            <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <label>Enter the team name
                <input type="text" name='tn' placeholder='Team name'/>
                </label>
                <br></br><br></br><br></br>
                <label>Enter the player name
                <input type="text" name='pn' placeholder='Player name'/>
                </label>
                <br></br><br></br><br></br>
                <label>Enter the player age
                <input type="number" name='pa' placeholder='Player age'/>
                </label>
                
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>


        </>
        
    )
}
```

I am using the multer middleware to fetch the file but i text fields of these form are not able to accessed in request body.

Comment: How is the form submitted to the server? I don't see an action in your form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example from the [Multer docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) (it says *req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any*, so the other fields are in `req.body`):

```js
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

---

PS. This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484700/how-to-create-a-form-with-text-and-file-input-in-react-and-send-form-data-to-ser#comment126348094_71484700) has got a point:

> How is the form submitted to the server? I don't see an action in your form element.

An `action` attribute ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action)) specifies the URL the data should be sent to. In this case, you should set your Express.js endpoint here.